# How to prepend text to each echo in a called script?

Tags: shell, posix

Let's say I have two scripts, one calls the other, how can I prepend text to each echo to visually indicate the echo comes from the called command?

**a.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo - BEGIN
./b.sh # Append "-" to each echo?
echo - END
```

**b.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo - BEGIN
echo - END
```

**Output I want:**

```
- BEGIN
-- BEGIN
-- END
- END
```

I can't touch **b.sh** and I need to stream the output.

Comment: What if `b.sh` contained a command other than `echo` and the command generated output? In general do you want the whole output from `b.sh` to be modified? or just output from `echo`s?

Answer (score 4):

If it's just text output by the `echo` command that you want prepended with a `-`, you could redefine `echo` as a function and *source* the other script with the `.` special builtin so it inherits that function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
printf '%s\n' '- BEGIN'
echo() {
  printf %s -
  command echo "$@"
}
. ./b.sh
printf '%s\n' '- END'
```

(note that in any case [`echo` is best avoided](/q/65803))

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to add this to all output printed by the second script, just pipe its output to `sed`. In your example, make `a.sh` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo - BEGIN
./b.sh | sed 's/^/-/' 
echo - END
```

This results in:

```
$ a.sh
- BEGIN
-- BEGIN
-- END
- END
```